# Blender Mesh is deforming when imported into Unity3D

Tags: animation, mesh, unity

So I have a small but rather annoying problem.

In Blender, I've created a very simple rigged mesh so that I can create animations.

In Blender, everything works perfectly. For example I will show a frame from one of my animations where my character puts her hands on her hips.

[image: Example frame of animation in Blender]

When I bring this model into Unity3D however, the elbows, knees and chin/head slightly deform into a curve, which is my problem.

[image: And this is the result when running the animation in the Unity scene]

Please let me know what you think! Thank you, very much for your time.

Additional information that may help:
I am running Blender 2.76b and Unity 5.3.4f1.
Also, my model has 3 modifiers (Skin, Armature, and Subsurf)

Comment: The modifiers are not exported with the model unless you apply them.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Denis, you were right on! I actually didn't get it right away because after I applied, then, exported, the mesh looked correct but actually wouldn't move. Some more fiddling around got me to what I was hoping for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has subsurface modifier applied after the animation deformation which didn't get applied when you exported your model.

So you should apply your subsurface modifier before you export your model.

**But,Your subsurface modifier should be at the top of the modifier stack in order to work correctly in Unity as you see it in blender.**

So move your subsurface modifier at the top after the skin modifier and apply it.

[image: modifiers]

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help Omar! I know it was simple however this is my first Blender project and I was very lost as to what to try next!

For other users with this same problem, I would just note that you may need to play around with the order in which you apply modifiers. I believe Omar is 100% correct in the proper ordering of modifiers...however as I probably did something else incorrectly, the order "Skin, Subsurf, then Armature" caused additional issues for my model in particular.

Thanks again Omar!